# UserTransaction doesn't commit

Tags: jsf, jpa, transactions, managed-bean

I'm trying to do a password reset with a JSF application, but the userTransaction doesn't work. I assign all the correct values to the entity and then I do utx.commit() but in the database nothing is changed. The message "password has been reset" is displayed and no error happens
Can you help me? here is the code:

```
package it.polimi.meteocal.business.control;

import it.polimi.meteocal.business.beans.SendEmailBean;
import it.polimi.meteocal.business.entity.User;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import javax.transaction.SystemException;
import javax.transaction.UserTransaction;

@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class AccessValidation {

    private String password;
    private String confpassword;
    private String username4email;
    private String message;
    private String email;
    private String username;

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    @EJB
    private CheckFields cf;

    @Resource
    UserTransaction utx;

    public void passwordReset() {

            Query query;
            User user;

            if (!cf.checkPassword(password, confpassword)) {
                message = "Passwords don't match";
            } else if (confpassword.length() < 6) {
                message = "Password should be at least 6 characters";
            } else {

                try {

                    query = em.createQuery("select u from User u where u.username=:um");
                    query.setParameter("um", username);
                    user = (User) query.getResultList().get(0);

                    utx.begin();

                    user.setPassword(password);

                    utx.commit();
                    message = "Password has been reset!";

                } catch (Exception e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                    try {
                        utx.rollback();
                    } catch (IllegalStateException | SecurityException | SystemException exception) {
                    }

                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: Make this statement `utx.begin();` the first statement in the only `try...catch` block. The thing is, the `Query` (along with `User`) instance is sitting outside the transaction boundary - make it a proper transactional unit. As a side note : You are already using EJBs as implied by the injection point (at `@EJB`). As such, why don't you simply migrate your business logic to its own place (in EJBs) and use container managed transactions instead of using these bean managed transactions manually (unless they are not absolutely necessary apparently).

Answer (score 1):

After `query.getResultList()`, the user is detached from entity manager. This is because the entity manager context lives from `utx.begin()` until `utx.commit()`. Any results of queries without active transaction are not contained in entity manager context.

Solution: Put your `utx.begin()` before your query.